# How can I embed responsive HTML into a flexdashboard using storyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard that uses the storyboard format. I am trying to embed the responsive timeline seen [here](https://codepen.io/knyttneve/pen/bgvmma) on one of the sections. It seems to me that calling the HTML via code-chunk places it within a chart-shim div with its own scroll bar, and that the JS does not respond to the div's scroll, only the outer window scroll.

For reference, I have created a folder called "www" in the directory containing the storyboard, and in that folder I have created a file called "script.js", "styles.css", and "timeline.html." The html file is the only one that I have modified from its original form, in that I have added the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='www/styles.css' charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

... (HTML as it originally appears)...

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="www/script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

````
---
title: reprex
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme:
      version: 5
      bootswatch: litera

runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(htmltools)
```

Report {.storyboard}
=========================================

### Section 1

```{r echo=FALSE}

htmltools::includeHTML('www/timeline.html') %>% HTML()

```

*** 
Some words about Section 1

### Section 2

About
=========================================
````

How can I embed the HTML (or modify the JS?) so that it is responsive?

A secondary issue is that embedding this HTML appears to mess with the functionality of the sections of the dashboard...if I call the HTML in a code chunk as shown below, the "About" section is no longer responsive to a click.

Comment: Since you're using `runtime: shiny`, do it the same way as in Shiny. You don't need to designate the UI or server or what might have gone in each.  Pretty sure having an extra newline in the YAML's no good, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Can you explain what you mean as "do it the same way in shiny"? I don't know how it would look different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY figured this out...instead of having the html reference external JS and CSS files, I bundled them all into the html file, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018109/bundle-html-js-and-css-into-one-index-html-file), and then used an iframe to call the html file:

```
         tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", 
                  src= 'www/timeline.html',
                  width='100%', 
                  height=800)
```